# Can't fill my state in componentDidMound function

Tags: reactjs

inside of my componentDidMount method I'm trying to make array of objects by using fetch. In my head it looks like this - on state I keep variable "loading" (true by default), and when my method is done with fetching it set it to false. On render method I've put if statement. But in real life my method filled array doesn't get executed (first console.log gets executed, second is not), . I'm losing my mind with this.

```
import { Company } from "../company/company.component";

export class CompanyList extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            tempResult: 10,
            newArray: [],
            loading: true,
        };
    }

    componentDidMount = () => {
        console.log(this.state.loading,"1");
        const filledArray = this.props.companies.map((item) => {
            fetch(`xxxx/incomes/${item.id}`)
                .then((response) => response.json())
                .then((data) => {
                    let transactionsToFloat = data.incomes.map((item) =>
                        parseFloat(item.value)
                    );
                    let result = transactionsToFloat.reduce((acc, num) => {
                        return acc + num;
                    }, 0);
                    result = Math.round(result * 100) / 100;
                    this.setState({ tempResult: result, loading: false });
                    console.log(item.id, item.name, item.city, result);
                    return {
                        id: item.id,
                        name: item.name,
                        city: item.city,
                        totalIncome: result,
                    };
                });
            this.setState({ loading: false });
            return true;

        });
        this.setState({ newArray: filledArray });
    };

    render() {
        if (this.state.loading) {
            return <h1>Loading...</h1>;
        } else if (!this.state.loading) {
            return (
                <div>
                    {/* <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Button</button> */}
                    <table>
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th> Id </th>
                                <th> Name </th>
                                <th> City </th>
                                <th> Total income </th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>

                        {this.state.newArray.map((item) => (
                            <Company key={item.id} company={item} />
                        ))}
                    </table>
                </div>
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Cheers

Comment: For ```this.props.companies``` in ```componentDidMount```, it seems to me that you are referring to the one in the ```Company``` component in your ```render``` function? If it is, the logic in your ```componentDidMount``` should handle in ```Company``` component.

Comment: You are missing a whole lot of await statements

Comment: It is refering to Company component, and before I had this fetch it in Company component. But the thing is, I need to have this here, because I need to sort it later on, and it was impossible when that was on child :(

Answer (score 1):

fetch is async, when you do `this.setState({ loading: false })` after fetch, this line of code will be executed right away, before promise is even resolved. you are also not returning the data, but `true` values instead.

given that you are executing an array of promises, you may consider return fetch promises and wrap your array of promises with a `Promise.all`:

```
Promise.all(this.props.companies.map((item) => { return fetch().then().then() })
  .then(results => this.setState({ newArray: results, loading: false }))
  .catch(error => ... handle error here)
```

there is a caveat that Promise.all will reject if one of the promises fails. if you dont want that behavior you could use `Promise.allSettled` instead. `allSettled` will never reject and it returns instead an array of objects, with `status` and `value` keys.

Comment: Thank you alot, gonna try this out!